# How to add tags after creating resource using TagAtScope in Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, pulumi

Trying to add tags after creating resource group as following (according to Pulumi doc: [Update tags on a resource](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/resources/tagatscope/#update-tags-on-a-resource))

```cs
// Create Resource Group
var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup("resourceGroup", new ResourceGroupArgs
{
    ResourceGroupName = "demo-rg",
    Location = "japaneast"
    //Tags = 
});

// Apply tags
var appliedTags = resourceGroup.Id.Apply(rgResourceId =>
{
    
    return new TagAtScope("demoTagAtScope", new TagAtScopeArgs
    {
        Scope = rgResourceId, // (scope) ResourceId -> xxx/yyy/zzz/...
        Properties = new TagsArgs()
        {
            Tags = {
                ["tagKey1"] = "value1",
                ["tagKey2"] = "value2"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**But getting the following error:**

```
azure-native:resources:TagAtScope (demoTagAtScope):
error: cannot create already existing resource '/subscriptions/xxx/demo-rg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default'
```

According to Microsoft doc: [Tags - Create Or Update At Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/create-or-update-at-scope), it should work.

Comment: Could you please open an issue in https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues?

Comment: @MikhailShilkov opened: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/1253